# How to get the count of one column with GROUP BY function in a INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the total qty one person has got for one date (group by date I guess).  How should I get it? This is the code I am working on.

```
SELECT  Dc.Name AS Market   
        ,R.Name AS Route    
        ,C.Id   
        ,C.ERPCusCode   
        ,C.Name 
        --,C.Address1 AS Address    
        ,(isnull(C.Address1,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address2,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address3,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address4,'')) AS Address
        ,C.CustomerGradeId AS volumeClass   
        ,I.ERPItemCode  
        ,H.InvoiceDate  
        ,D.Qty
FROM InvoiceHeader H
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail D ON H.InvoiceNo=D.InvoiceNo
INNER JOIN ItemMaster I ON I.Id=D.ItemMasterId
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.Id=H.CustomerId
INNER JOIN DistributionCenter Dc ON Dc.Id=H.DistributionCenterId
INNER JOIN Route R ON R.Id=H.RouteId

WHERE H.Deleted=0 AND H.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/06/06'
AND C.Active=1
```

Comment: It would help if you edited the questo on to add sample data and the output expected from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUM(D.Qty) as Total_QTY
```

then use `GROUP BY H.InvoiceDate` and rest of your columns.
Just be wary if your `H.InvoiceDate` is a DateTime, and not Date, results might not look like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want obtain both detailed info returned by the query you show and "total qty one person has got for a one date" added to each record, you may add the following expression to the output list:

```
SUM(D.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Id, H.InvoiceDate) AS Daily_got_qty
```

So full query text will be

```
SELECT Dc.Name AS Market   
        ,R.Name AS Route    
        ,C.Id   
        ,C.ERPCusCode   
        ,C.Name 
        --,C.Address1 AS Address    
        ,(isnull(C.Address1,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address2,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address3,'')+' '+isnull(C.Address4,'')) AS Address
        ,C.CustomerGradeId AS volumeClass   
        ,I.ERPItemCode  
        ,H.InvoiceDate  
        ,D.Qty
        ,SUM(D.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Id, H.InvoiceDate) AS Daily_got_qty
FROM InvoiceHeader H
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail D ON H.InvoiceNo=D.InvoiceNo
INNER JOIN ItemMaster I ON I.Id=D.ItemMasterId
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.Id=H.CustomerId
INNER JOIN DistributionCenter Dc ON Dc.Id=H.DistributionCenterId
INNER JOIN Route R ON R.Id=H.RouteId
WHERE H.Deleted=0 AND H.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/06/06'
AND C.Active=1
```

If the `InvoiceHeader.InvoiceDate` field datatype is not `DATE` (if it contain the time component), you must cast it in added expression to the `DATE` datatype:

```
SUM(D.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Id, CAST(H.InvoiceDate AS DATE)) AS Daily_got_qty
```

Comment: This is also works i guess I do not know about PARTITIONING yet.Thank You